# SAXParseException with Camel 4

Tags: java, apache-camel, xerces, spring-camel

```
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 4268; columnNumber: 51; cos-nonambig: "http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring":onFallback and "http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring":onFallback (or elements from their substitution group) violate "Unique Particle Attribution". During validation against this schema, ambiguity would be created for those two particles.

      at org.apache.xerces.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(Unknown Source)
      at org.apache.xerces.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.error(Unknown Source)
      at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
      at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
      at org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.XSConstraints.reportSchemaError(Unknown Source)
      at org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.XSConstraints.fullSchemaChecking(Unknown Source)
      at org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.XMLSchemaLoader.loadGrammar(Unknown Source)
      at org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.XMLSchemaLoader.loadGrammar(Unknown Source)
      at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.validation.XMLSchemaFactory.newSchema(Unknown Source)
```

I'm getting this error when trying to create a new schema from camel-spring.xsd after updated Camel version to 4.0.4 and Java 17

The code is this one, and the error happens in the last line:

```
import com.google.common.io.Resources;

import javax.xml.XMLConstants;
import javax.xml.transform.Source;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamSource;
import javax.xml.validation.SchemaFactory;
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


public class Camel
{

    public static void main( String[] args ) throws Exception
    {
       SchemaFactory schemaFactory = SchemaFactory.newInstance(XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI);

       List<Source> tmp = new ArrayList();

       String loc = "camel-spring.xsd";

       URL url = Resources.getResource(loc);
       byte[] bytes = Resources.toByteArray(url);
       StreamSource src = new StreamSource(new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes));
       tmp.add(src);

       schemaFactory.newSchema((Source[]) tmp.toArray(new Source[tmp.size()]));
    }
}
```

Have you ever seen this error?

I have seen that up camel-spring.xsd 4.x (https://camel.apache.org/schema/spring/) on circuitBreakerDefinition element has two "onFallBack" elements and this is the error. When I comment one of those, I don't get an error. But I can't modify the jar, do you know if there is a way to get the schema from the xsd Camel 4.x?

[camel-spring.xsd](https://i.stack.imgur.com/avQ76.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try setting this feature to false:

```
schemaFactory.setFeature("http://apache.org/xml/features/validation/schema-full-checking", false);
```

[This](https://xerces.apache.org/xerces2-j/features.html#validation.schema-full-checking) (very old) documentation mentions that "unique particle attribution" is one of the checks turned off.

Answer (score 0):

A 'org.xml.sax.SAXParseException' usually indicates there is a problem parsing data as XML. It happens in a line where you load a schema - but hey: A schema is also some XML document. Hence the problem lies either how you load the data, or the data itself that you load (you only show your code).

- ensure the resource you are trying to load is wellformed XML and valid
- check if your code accesses the correct resource (maybe print the URL to log or console, load and print the stream content)
- check if the code correctly passes your InputStream to the Camel functions so they can make sense of it

Looking at the full error message I assume the problem is in your schema at line number 4268. Look at the 'onFallback' or similar elements.

Comment: It's not an error on the XML because I'm using that xsd on camel-spring.xml jar. I have tried other ways to parse it, but still getting the same error. Could be maybe a question of a compatible version of Camel 4.0.4 and Javax Validator?